# How can I find an equivalent of The Circle of Fifths in different equal temperaments?

Tags: theory, temperament

I have mathematically figured out how to map the chromatic scale onto the circle of fifths for even temperaments. The equation is to multiply each interval by `(n/2)+1` where n is the n TET.
For example, for 12 TET, we apply the function `(n/2)+1` and get 7 ((12/2)+1=7), from there I multiply each interval by 7:
0 semitones * 7 = 0 semitones (eg: C is mapped to C);
1 semitone * 7 = 7 semitones (eg: C# is mapped to G);
2 semitone * 7 = 14 semitones (eg: D is mapped to D);
3 semitone * 7 = 21 semitones (eg: D# is mapped to A)
etc...
This will give me 12 TET circle of fifths.

However, I've noticed this equation only works for even temperaments because for odd temperaments, we have to multiply by a number with a half, giving me quartertones.
Are there no odd temperament circle of fifths equivalent?
Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: As stated, this isn't possible to answer because you haven't defined what you mean by a "circle of fifths equivalent".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a circle of any number of steps mutually prime to the total number of pitches in the octave.

Comment: However I'm looking for a circle with the same amount of steps as pitches within the octave, with circle of fifths capabilities; for example: a representation of key signatures. Therefore the number of steps round the circle cannot be coprime to the total number of pitches on the octave.

Comment: @Mixtli I'm not sure I understand. Any coprime number of steps will touch every pitch in the octave.

Comment: Here's a Desmos graph to try visualise what I mean: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/numhfst4fg

Comment: the numbers 0 - n represent each note within an octave of the TET, x axis is the chromatic scale and the y is what it is mapped to.
you can see that 7 and 5 map 12TET one-to-one to itself, this is the mapping to the cirlce of fifths/fourths. I cant seem to find anything similar for 13TET because everything maps one-to-one to itself

Comment: @Mixtli That's because everything is mutually prime to 13. The "circle of fifths" is a special property of 12n-TET because of the harmonic (i.e., frequency ratio) relationship between the fourth/fifth and octave. for other ETs, you would have to create your own rules governing harmony.

Comment: @Mixtli 12 is very divisible, so you cannot have a circle of whole steps, minor thirds, major thirds, tritones, minor sixths, major sixths, or minor sevenths, because none of these interval sizes (2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10) is coprime to 12.  You can have a circle of fourths, of fifths, and of major sevenths (a "circle" of minor seconds is perhaps not a circle, depending on your definition; it seems like more of a straight line).  I also note that the rule articulated here is independent of the equality of the temperament; it only depends on the number of divisions of the octave.

Comment: That is, the circle of fifths exists in the 12-tone system regardless of the temperament.  Similarly, there is a circle of "fifths" in [22-tone systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_equal_temperament) because the fifth is 13 divisions in size, and 13 is coprime with 22.  By contrast, the perfect fifth in [34-tone systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/34_equal_temperament) is 20 divisions wide, so the circle of fifths in that system doesn't reach every pitch class, because 34 and 20 share the common prime factor of 2.

Comment: @phoog Great point. I'll expand my answer when I get the chance.

Comment: @Aaron every number between 1 and 12 is coprime to 13, but not every integer is coprime to 13.

Comment: My comment about unequal divisions of the octave is perhaps slightly overbroad; it does assume that the divisions are roughly the same size, so that every (for example) 20-division-of-34 interval can be seen as the approximation of a fifth.  Back to the 12-tone example, if we were to divide the octave very unevenly, say into intervals of 200 cents and 50 cents, then the assumption that a 7-division interval is a fifth probably breaks down.  But still, there would be a closed circle of seven-division intervals, whatever we decided to call that interval.

Comment: Also, "cannot have a closed circle of X" above should be "cannot have a closed circle of X that reaches every pitch class."  The 12-tone circle of minor sixths is closed, but from C it only reaches A flat and E (enharmonically equivalent to F flat), before returning to C.  There are therefore four such circles with distinct identities (modulo enharmonic equivalence).

Comment: @Mixtli "the number of steps round the circle cannot be coprime to the total number of pitches on the octave": the number that must be coprime to the number of divisions of the octave is the number of divisions comprised in the "of" interval. For example, in the 12-tone system, the _fifth_ comprises 7 divisions, which ensures that the number of steps to close the circle "of fifths" is _equal to_ the number of divisions in the octave, equivalent to ensuring that the circle reaches every pitch class. By contrast, the minor sixth has 8 divisions, so there are only three steps to close the circle.

Comment: I think I understand now, heres another desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9rl6q6ilxl. Here I added an extra object where each point represents the gcd between n of the n-Temperament and every integer up to it along the x axis. when one of these points lie on y=1, its x value is coprime to n, therefore, when you set the variable b to such x value (and un-hide the folder), it should make a one-to-one mapping of the chromatic scale onto different notes of itself, from x to y.

Comment: What dictates whether one of these mappings is considered a type of "circle of fifths" is how well one of the notes in the temperament correspond to the relationship of a fifth. This is what I have understood, let me know if I'm wrong!
Edit: I also see now why 13-Temperament was a bad choice given its prime and is therefore co-prime to all integers from 1 to 13

Comment: @Mixtli - that's the problem with the whole concept of "circle of fifths".  Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a circle of fifths, because no power of two (the circle= beginning note and end note being some number of octaves apart) can equal a power of three (the fifth).  The question is thus illdefined.